# How to sort alphabetically a UITableView Sectioned?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, sorting

I have a sectioned UITableView with 3 categories. I'm using this code:

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", "three", "four", nil];
    NSDictionary *dictOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayOne forKey:@"Elements"];
```

for each category.

How can i sort them alphabetically? I've read some answers here but i didn't found out anything.

If i use the code in this answer [Method for sorting custom objects alphabetically in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748371/method-for-sorting-custom-objects-alphabetically-in-uitableview) it doesn't work. 
i have the code:

```
[listObjects addObject:dictOne];
```

and if i put

```
[listOfTitles sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter];
```

It doesn't work.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", "three", "four", nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOne sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


NSDictionary *dictOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sortedArray forKey:@"Elements"];
```